# Overriding class properties with lazy properties

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, overriding

Is overriding properties with a `lazy` property legal?

The following code output:

```
Created CardMatchingGame (Matchismo, mode: 1, 30 cards)
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Which means that the Matchismo game is created but later not found by the base class function updateScoreLabel().

```
class CardGameViewController: UIViewController {
   var game: CardMatchingGame!
   @IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!
   ...

   func updateScoreLabel() {
      self.scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(self.game.getGameScore())"
   }
   ...
}

class PlayingCardGameViewController: CardGameViewController {
  lazy override var game: CardMatchingGame! = MatchismoGame()
  ...
}
```

Comment: just to clarify, is that fatal error from the lazy override line, or from some other optional

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write it. It's and error thrown by the updateScoreLabel from the CardGameViewController. I also forgot to mention that MatchismoGame is a subclass of CardMatchingGame. I'm wondering what's wrong, because the game property is created but when used by the function it throws a nil-value error.

Comment: another silly check, but make sure the label is not nil, check if you can change the text of that okay without calling getGameScore()

Comment: checked, it's the game property that's causing problems.

Comment: additional info. If I override the updateScoreLabel() function in my subclasses everything works fine. Is it a problem with OOP? I understand that if a base-class function uses some property inside itself and in th subclass the property is overridden and the inherited function is called it operates on the inherited but overridden property?

Comment: from the docs it seems potentially you want to call the overridden property as super.property. This might be of more use to you because you have your whole code there: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html

Comment: @chris, how would calling super.property help in this situation? The problem is that in the subclass the base class function is using the base class property instead of the overridden property 